# How to change Tab title font for TabBar in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, tabbar, maui, .net-maui

In my AppShell.xaml I have the following code for a TabBar. I can't seem to find a property or anything that allows me to change the font (and font size etc.) of the title.

```
<TabBar x:Name="TabBar">
    <Tab x:Name="HomePage" Title="Home" Icon="tab_home.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Even in `Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml` I don't see a property in the shell or tabbedpage for font family.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot change the font and size of the Title text on TabBar Tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set Font Icons in Shell Tabs.

Please refer to the following code:

1.add the font you wanted.

```
public static class MauiProgram 
{
      public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
      {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                // add your font here
                fonts.AddFont("icomoon.ttf", "FA");
            }); 

            return builder.Build();
      }
}
```

2.Usage:

```
<TabBar> 
    <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="{FontImage FontFamily=FA , Glyph=&#xe922;}" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CatsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Items" Icon="{FontImage FontFamily=FA , Glyph=&#xe910;}" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

**Note:**

Please add the font into folder `Fonts` and make sure the build action is `MauiFont`.

Comment: I think that Cody wants to change the Font and size of the Title text of the TabBar Tabs, which is not possible, AFAIK.

Comment: While that is a good workaround, @ewerspej is correct, you can't change icon/font sizes in TabBars, I ended up using Syncfusion's TabView which allows for more customization.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't work and cannot change the font of the title in the TabBar. Please review my answer. I tested it and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer in [how can i remove or hide the text of tabs in TabBar .NET MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75657132/how-can-i-remove-or-hide-the-text-of-tabs-in-tabbar-net-maui)

You can change both the font and the font size of the title in the TabBar.

In Android:

You need to add a custom renderer in `Platforms/Android/Renderers`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Shell), typeof(CustomShellRenderer))]
namespace YourApp.Platforms.Android.Renderers;
    
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new CustomBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(this, shellItem);
    }
}
public class CustomBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);

            // Set custom font with any font file name you need as registered in MauiProgram.cs builder.ConfigureFonts()
            var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(ShellContext.AndroidContext.Assets, "FONTFILENAME.ttf");
            // replace FONTSIZE with you needed font size
            var spanFace = new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font, FONTSIZE);
            // if you need you can change the direction of the bottom navigation view
            bottomView.LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Rtl;
            var menu = bottomView.Menu;
            for (var i = 0; i < menu.Size(); i++)
            {
                // Set custom label with custom fonts
                var menuItem = menu.GetItem(i);
                if (menuItem == null) continue;
                var spannableString = new SpannableString(menuItem.TitleCondensedFormatted);
                spannableString.SetSpan(spanFace, 0, spannableString.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
                menuItem.SetTitle(spannableString);
            }
     
    }
    public CustomBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem) : base(shellContext, shellItem)
    {
        ShellContext = shellContext;
    }
    private IShellContext ShellContext { get; }
  }
}
public class CustomTypefaceSpan : TypefaceSpan
{
    private float? FontSize { get; }
    private readonly Typeface _typeface;
    public CustomTypefaceSpan(string family, Typeface typeface, float? fontSize = null) : base(family)
    {
        FontSize = fontSize;
        _typeface = typeface;
    }
    public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
    {
        ApplyCustomTypeFace(ds, _typeface);
    }
    public override void UpdateMeasureState(TextPaint paint)
    {
        ApplyCustomTypeFace(paint, _typeface);
    }
    private void ApplyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf)
    {
        if (FontSize != null && FontSize != 0)
            paint.TextSize = FontSize.Value;
        paint.SetTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

In `MauiProgram.cs` add to `builder` object that call

```
 .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(Platforms.Android.Renderers.CustomShellRenderer));
#endif
            });
```

I will look into iOS and update the code accordingly.