# How to change the FontSize and icons size of .net Maui iOS AppShell TabBar?

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I have this AppShell:

```
    <Shell.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle"
           TargetType="Element">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor"
                Value="{DynamicResource YouviRed}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor"
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor"
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor"
                Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor"
                Value="#95FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.NavBarIsVisible" 
                Value="False" />
    </Style>
</Shell.Resources>
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="{ext:Translate Dashboard}" 
                  Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
                  Icon="dashboard.png" 
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate navi:CustomNavigationPage}" 
                  Route="Dashboard"  >
        <dash:DashboardView/>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Title="{ext:Translate Rooms}" 
                  Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
                  Icon="rooms.png" 
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate navi:CustomNavigationPage}" 
                  Route="Rooms" >
        <rooms:RoomsView/>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent  Title="{ext:Translate Settings}"
                   Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"
                   Icon="settings.png" 
                   ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate navi:CustomNavigationPage}" 
                   Route="Settings"  >
        <sett:SettingsView />
    </ShellContent>
</TabBar>
```

The Titles fontSize of the iOS TabBar are to small and the icons are to big, I don't know how to change this. Did I need an specific Handler for this or did anyone knows an better way ? I would be very grateful for any help, thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Setting BaseSize for the svg files (which are the source of the icons) in csproj file did not work for me. As a workaround I created svg files with the desired size.
Basically I would rather use Fontawesome for the Icons, but they only show on Android, not on iOS, although this should be resolved according to this Github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4774

Comment: @Lilly Hi, could you please check my answer.? Set the BaseSize does work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the BaseSize of svg file works for me.

You could add the line in csproj file:

```
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\airplane.svg" BaseSize="50,50" />
```

You could control the size by change to `BaseSize="30,30"` or other value. So the Build action of SVG file is MauiImage.

As far as i know we could not change the font size of shell Tabbar. See this thread: [How to change Tab title font for TabBar in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248348/how-to-change-tab-title-font-for-tabbar-in-net-maui). You could also raise an issue on [Github.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues)

Hope it works.

Comment: Yes, the BaseSize is the key, thanks. At iOS you must set this BaseSize for all Mauiimages, for Android it dosent need to be. For example I dont set an BaseSize for the splash image and the whole iOS app Size  was much to small.